# do-release-upgrade from local mirror does not work

Tags: upgrade, 10.04, do-release-upgrade

I have setup a local mirror to update various PCs/Servers running behind a very **slow** DSL connection. I have **LTS** version of lucid,precise and trusty stored depending on the needs...

I have update the *meta-release-lts* file, downloaded the *i18n* files, and the dist-upgrades files.

I am testing various upgrade processed through a *VM* of Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS. Standard and basic initial install. No external sources (i.e. non ubuntu).

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release:        10.04
Codename:       lucid

uname -r
2.6.32-21-server
```

Normal update/upgrade works. The client find the mirror and processes the upgrade.

When trying to do a release upgrade the process fails. From the screenlog.0 log in the `/var/log/dist-upgrade` folder I can see the following (Sorry a bit long):

```
Building data structures... Done 

Updating repository information
WARNING: Failed to read mirror file

No valid mirror found 

While scanning your repository information no mirror entry for the 
upgrade was found. This can happen if you run a internal mirror or if 
the mirror information is out of date. 

Do you want to rewrite your 'sources.list' file anyway? If you choose 
'Yes' here it will update all 'lucid' to 'precise' entries. 
If you select 'No' the upgrade will cancel. 

Continue [yN] y
 WARNING: Failed to read mirror file

<snip>


Building data structures... 99%

Building data structures... 99%

Building data structures... 99%


Building data structures... Done 

Updating repository information
WARNING: Failed to read mirror file

0% [Working]                                                                   
0% [Working]                                                                   
0% [Connecting to 192.168.1.205]                                               
0% [Connecting to 192.168.1.205]                                               
0% [Connecting to 192.168.1.205 (192.168.1.205)]                               
0% [Connecting to 192.168.1.205 (192.168.1.205)]                               
0% [Waiting for headers]                                                       
0% [Waiting for headers]                                                       
Ign http://192.168.1.205 precise InRelease                                     

12% [Working]                                                                  
12% [Working]                                                                  
12% [Waiting for headers]                                                      
12% [Waiting for headers]                                                      
Get:1 http://192.168.1.205 precise-updates InRelease [196 kB]                  

0% [1 InRelease 0 B/196 kB 0%]                                                 
0% [1 InRelease 0 B/196 kB 0%]                                                 
99% [Working]                                                                  
99% [Working]                                                                  
Get:2 http://192.168.1.205 precise-security InRelease [54.5 kB]       

<snip>

Building data structures... Done 

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Error authenticating some packages 

It was not possible to authenticate some packages. This may be a 
transient network problem. You may want to try again later. See below 
for a list of unauthenticated packages. 

accountsservice 
apparmor 
apparmor-utils 
apport 
apport-symptoms 
apt 
apt-transport-https 
apt-utils 
apt-xapian-index 
aptitude 
base-files 
bash 
bash-completion 
bc 
bind9-host 
bsdutils 
busybox-initramfs 
busybox-static 
ca-certificates 
coreutils 
cpio 
cron 
dbus 
dhcp3-client 
dhcp3-common 
dmidecode 
dmsetup 
dnsutils 
dosfstools 
dpkg 
e2fslibs 
e2fsprogs 
ecryptfs-utils 
file 
fuse 
fuse-utils 
gnupg 
gnupg-curl 
gpgv 
grub-common 
grub-pc 
grub-pc-bin 
grub2-common 
hdparm 
ifupdown 
initramfs-tools 
initramfs-tools-bin 
initscripts 
iproute 
iptables 
isc-dhcp-client 
isc-dhcp-common 
krb5-locales 
landscape-common 
language-pack-en 
language-pack-en-base 
language-selector-common 
libaccountsservice0 
libapparmor-perl 
libapparmor1 
libapt-inst1.4 
libapt-pkg4.12 
libasn1-8-heimdal 
libbind9-80 
libblkid1 
libc-bin 
libc6 
libcomerr2 
libcurl3-gnutls 
libdbus-1-3 
libdbus-glib-1-2 
libdevmapper1.02.1 
libdns81 
libdrm-intel1 
libdrm-nouveau1a 
libdrm-radeon1 
libdrm2 
libecryptfs0 
libelf1 
libevent-2.0-5 
libexpat1 
libfreetype6 
libfuse2 
libgc1c2 
libgcrypt11 
libglib2.0-0 
libgnutls26 
libgssapi-krb5-2 
libgssapi3-heimdal 
libhcrypto4-heimdal 
libheimbase1-heimdal 
libheimntlm0-heimdal 
libhx509-5-heimdal 
libisc83 
libisccc80 
libisccfg82 
libk5crypto3 
libkrb5-26-heimdal 
libkrb5-3 
libkrb5support0 
libldap-2.4-2 
liblockfile-bin 
liblockfile1 
liblwres80 
libmagic1 
libmount1 
libnih-dbus1 
libnih1 
libnspr4 
libnss3 
libnss3-1d 
libparted0debian1 
libpci3 
libpciaccess0 
libpcre3 
libplymouth2 
libpolkit-gobject-1-0 
libpython2.7 
libroken18-heimdal 
libsasl2-2 
libsasl2-modules 
libsqlite3-0 
libss2 
libssl0.9.8 
libssl1.0.0 
libtasn1-3 
libudev0 
libuuid1 
libwind0-heimdal 
libx11-6 
libx11-data 
libxcb1 
libxext6 
libxml-libxml-perl 
libxml-sax-perl 
libxml2 
linux-firmware 
linux-headers-3.2.0-92 
linux-headers-3.2.0-92-generic 
linux-headers-server 
linux-image-3.2.0-92-generic 
linux-image-server 
linux-server 
login 
lsb-base 
lsb-release 
make 
man-db 
mime-support 
mount 
mountall 
multiarch-support 
ntfs-3g 
ntpdate 
openssh-client 
openssh-server 
openssl 
parted 
passwd 
patch 
pciutils 
perl 
perl-base 
perl-modules 
plymouth 
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text 
ppp 
procps 
psmisc 
python 
python-apport 
python-apt 
python-apt-common 
python-central 
python-crypto 
python-gi 
python-gobject 
python-httplib2 
python-keyring 
python-lazr.restfulclient 
python-minimal 
python-openssl 
python-problem-report 
python2.7 
python2.7-minimal 
resolvconf 
rsyslog 
sudo 
sysv-rc 
sysvinit-utils 
tcpdump 
tzdata 
ubuntu-keyring 
ubuntu-minimal 
ubuntu-standard 
udev 
update-manager-core 
update-notifier-common 
upstart 
util-linux 
uuid-runtime 
vim 
vim-common 
vim-runtime 
vim-tiny 
w3m 
wget 
wpasupplicant 
xkb-data 


Restoring original system state

Aborting

Reading package lists
```

What calls to attention is the following lines:

```
Error authenticating some packages 

It was not possible to authenticate some packages. This may be a 
transient network problem. You may want to try again later. See below 
for a list of unauthenticated packages.
```

And the process stops there after reversing the initial steps.

I can't see what I am missing. Anyone with an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: See [bug 1513232](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1513232) for details and work-arounds.